# How to safely migrate www domain name of my google app engine instance to a compute engine vm instance?

Tags: domain-name, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I have a need to reconfigure the custom domain name of my google app engine instance and I would like to have the SF community to review the plan.

**The issue**

When my project first starts as a google app engine, I have assigned 'www.mycompany.com' as the custom domain of the production instance of my GAE app.

As the project grows, we deployed a word-pressed powered managed VM to host blog posts and other marketing artefacts. The domain name is `about.mycompany.com`

It causes a lot of confusion to users because `www.mycompany.com/home` will reach the web app, but `www.mycompany.com` redirects users to `about.mycompany.com`. Once they reached `about.mycompany.com`, they have trouble to get back to `www.mycompany.com/home`

**Summary: current configuration**

`www.mycompany.com/home`: My web app
`www.mycompany.com/`: redirects user away to `about.mycompany.com`
`about.mycompany.com`: marketing stuff/blog

**My Desired Configuration**

1. Map `www.mycompany.com` to existing `about.mycompany.com`
2. Map `app.mycompany.com` to existing `www.mycompany.com` (the GAE instance)
3. Redirect `www.mycompany.com/home` to `app.mycompany.com/home`

My Question:

Regarding step 3 above, Google app engine has very good built-in load balancing. I am reluctant to put any apache instance (the one in the wordpress server) in front of the GAE instance because it can be easily DDOS for example. How can I make it less likely to go down under load? Is there any other alternative.

Is there any other additional issue I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I'd first add the custom domain `app.mycompany.com` directly to the GAE app (not as a DNS redirect). This will allow the GAE app to serve both `www` (no impact to existing functionality) and `app` (new functionality).

Now check that the `/home` path points correctly on the WP VM site, but without pointing to `www`, which you plan to change (it already does on the GAE app site):

- `about.mycompany.com/home` -> `app.mycompany.com/home`

You may also like to have links on both sites pointing to each-other, for easy cross-site navigation:

- `about.mycompany.com/app` -> `app.mycompany.com`
- `about.mycompany.com/www` -> `about.mycompany.com`
- `app.mycompany.com/app` -> `app.mycompany.com`
- `app.mycompany.com/www` -> `about.mycompany.com`

Now you can change the `www.mycompany.com` mapping from the GAE app to the WP VM. There should be no issue during DNS propagation, as regardless of which site `www.mycompany.com` points to its `/home`, `/app` and `/about` paths are redirected the right destination.

Now you can update the `/www` links, which would allow to eventually deprecate and drop the `about.mycompany.com` domain down the road:

- `about.mycompany.com/www` -> `www.mycompany.com`
- `app.mycompany.com/www` -> `www.mycompany.com`

While updating the above answer I just thought of another possibility :)

It appears that it is possible to run a Wordpress site on GAE. Plenty of docs on the subject: https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=host+wordpress+on+google+app+engine

Which means it's possible to deploy your existing WP site as a separate service/module of your **existing** GAE app, which would make the whole story a lot easier and completely eliminate the scalability concern of the apache instance infront of the GAE app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think you might have misread my question. `www.mycompany.com/home ` is where the web app is at the moment. It is not the blog/frontpage. That's why I mentioned the need for using an apache frontend to rewrite the incoming url

Comment: OK, now you lost me :) You can only map a **subdomain** to an app, not just a sub-path under a subdomain. I mean if `www.mycompany.com/home` is the GAE app then `www.mycompany.com` is the same GAE app.

Comment: The subpath is of course not controlled by DNS. It is achieved via the app.yaml https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref

Comment: That's what I thought. But I *think* I missed your desire to keep `www.mycompany.com/home` pointing to the GAE app. I'll update the answer.